# onsubmit event not working for asynchronous form submit

Tags: javascript, struts2, dom-events, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have created a form using struts tags. I have submitted the form asynchronously using struts jQuery's submit tag. Now before I submit my form i want to call a JavaScript function `checkUser()`, that checks if there is some client side error And prevents the form from submitting. The form with the JavaScript function is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        
        var xmlhttp;
        var k = document.getElementById("register_userDetails_username").value;
        
        var urls = "pass.jsp?ver=" + k;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById("err1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", urls, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function checkuser() {
          alert("hi");  
            var i = document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML.search("Unavailable");
            alert(i);
            var j= document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML.search("Min length:8");
            alert(j);
            if (i!= -1 || j!=-1) {
                alert("hello");
                return false;
            } 
            alert("false");
            return false;
      } 
     
</script>


    
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<jsp:include page="menubar.jsp"></jsp:include>
<s:form action="register" method="post" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form1" style="margin:8px 211px" onsubmit="return checkuser()">
    <div class="searchHeader">Sign Up</div>  
    <div id="passwordMatchError">
        <s:property value="error"/>
    </div>
    <s:textfield label="Name" name="userDetails.name" maxlength="30"/>
    <s:textfield label="Username"  name="userDetails.username" onkeyup="loadXMLDoc()" maxlength="30">
        <div id="err1"></div>
    </s:textfield> 
    <s:password label="Password" name="userDetails.password" maxlength="45"/>
    <s:hidden name="userDetails.role" value='U' />
    <s:password name="confirmPassword" label="Confirm Password" maxlength="45"/>
    <s:radio label="Sex" name="userDetails.sex" list="#{'M':'Male','F':'Female'}" />
    <s:textfield label="Phone No" name="userDetails.phoneno" maxlength="10"/>
    <s:textfield label="E-mail" name="userDetails.email" maxlength="45"/>
    <div id="submitdivid"> 
        <sj:submit value="SUBMIT" cssClass="orangebuttonsmall" targets="mainContent" id="sas" />
    </div>
</s:form>
```

Now when I enter some value in username field that already exist in db, then it shows string `Unavailable` in div having id as `err`.

On `onsubmit` event of form , I have called `checkuser` method. But with `sj:submit`, `onsubmit` event is *not* working. Can anyone help me with how to call make this `onsubmit` work My aim is to prevent form from submitting, if there exists the String `Unavailable` or `Min Length:8` in div `err`. Any alternative solutions are also accepted.

Comment: How did you handle the event?

Comment: @RomanC I have called checkuser() method when this event is fired. There i have checked certain conditions which when found true,i want to prevent form from submittting. But with sj:submit tag, this event is not working..

Comment: Do you have an evidence of that  event is fired? And I don't understand what is not working: preventing a form from submitting or `sj:submit` tag.

Comment: @RomanC The problem is when i use sj:submit tag, onsubmit event is not fired.

Comment: That tag doesn't have such event.

Comment: @RomanC The complete scene is like this. I have created a form using <s:form>. I have called a function on onsubmit event of this form using <s:form onsubmit="return someFunction()">. Now if i use <sj:submit> to submit this form, then that event is not fired i.e. control doesn't go to that someFunction(). And if i use<s:submit> to submit the form the event gets fired. Now i dont understand the reason for this....

Comment: The reason is they reproduce different behavior between normal request and Ajax request. If `sj:submit` have `s:submit` like behavior then there should be switch between request.

Comment: @RomanC My purpose is to call a function when i submit this form and if certain conditions checks becomes true in it, then the form should not be submitted. How can i accomplish this using sj:submit?

Comment: You can use `s:if` tag to make a choice between two submits.

Answer (score 3):

In Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.subscribe('beforeSubmit', function(event,data) {
        event.originalEvent.options.submit = checkuser();          
    });
</script>
```

In your tag:

```
<sj:submit value = "SUBMIT" 
        cssClass = "orangebuttonsmall" 
         targets = "mainContent" 
              id = "sas" 
  onBeforeTopics = "beforeSubmit"
/>
```

Comment: Onclick event works fine with the tag but this doesn't prevent form from submitting..

Comment: if you return false, it should. At least, it works with <s:submit>, not sure with <sj:submit>

Comment: yaa i agree. It works with s:submit. Problem lies with sj:submit. It doesn't work with it...

Comment: I've rewrited the answer consistently; totally untested solution, though, just try and let me know. To avoid confusion, always return a value from your function.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: It is not working and the form is submiting! I am using struts jquery last version ( 3.7.0 ). as far as I reviewed at http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1039 this option was a suggestion and not implemented

Comment: Ok, [it was a bug](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=617), but it should have been fixed in 3.2.1 :|

Comment: I'm using 3.7.0 too and I just checked, [the fix](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/detail?r=1559) is there, line 1130 :| Are you sure it is not working ?

Comment: Sorry for being too late! I found this will not prevent ajax validation if the form has validateFunction and has validate=true!