# struts 2 jquery plugin prevent form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, struts2, struts2-jquery

In Struts2 jQuery plugin, we defined forms with ajax validation. But some times we want  to prevent form begin validated via ajax and submitted.

I see some similar issue which changed the Struts 2 jQuery core which i prefer not to do it: [struts2 jquery ajax and client side validatio not working toghether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684370/struts2-jquery-ajax-and-client-side-validatio-not-working-toghether)

**For first try:**

I add onBeforeTopics="beforeFormSubmit" and below method:

```
$.subscribe("beforeFormSubmit", function(event, data) {
// Here nothing can stop event!!

});
```

So is there any way I can prevent the form from being submitted by subscribing to **onBeforeTopics**?!

**For second approach:**

I try to prevent form submiting by:

```
$( "#loginForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    alert('Before submit');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But surprisingly the above will not trigger and I don't see any alert! After some tests I find the above submit event handler:

```
<s:submit/> //This will trigger the submit event
<sj:submit/> //This will NOT trigger the submit event
```

Can I some how do it with javascript events ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19950126/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios: It is not working and the form is submitting! I am using struts jquery last version ( 3.7.0 ). as far as I reviewed at http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1039 this option was a suggestion and not implemented